Problems with suspend and dock
I have a Dell Latitude 7340 with 24.04 installed.
For the last few weeks, I've had two (possibly related?) problems.
First, the computer appears to suspend, but it is not. It stays warm to the touch and loses 50% of the battery overnight.
Second, about half of the time when I unplug from my USB-C docking station, it will freeze and restart.
Looking at the logs from the last time this happened, I see:
 5:30:53 PM systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-ubuntu\x2dreport\x2don\x2dupgrade-219982.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
 5:30:51 PM gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
 5:30:38 PM systemd: Failed to start org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service - GNOME XSettings service.
 5:30:37 PM apport-gtk: Can't create a GtkStyleContext without a display connection
 5:30:37 PM systemd: Failed to start org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service - GNOME Wacom tablet support service.
 5:30:24 PM kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
 5:30:24 PM kernel: pcieport 0000:02:04.0: Unable to change power state from D3hot to D0, device inaccessible
 5:25:31 PM pipewire: pw.node: (bluez_output.FE_79_CA_9D_F6_28.1-76) idle -> error (Received error event)
 5:25:31 PM bluetoothd: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)

And a whole bunch of Failed to start org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XXXXXX.service messages.
Thanks in advance for any pointers!
